# delay on hover for tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So, this is what my issue is. When someone hovers over a group, the new text shows up but it causes this feeling of dizzy because it auto formats during resize. What I want, if possible is to delay the text showing up until the resize is done. Is this possible and if so, what would I do? I need this to be 100% tailwind as I am challenging myself not to use any JS.

```
<div class="flex flex-row h-screen bg-white">
            <div class="group justify-center flex items-center hover:grayscale min-h-full transition-width transform delay-200 duration-500 bg-black xl:hover:w-3/4 w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 xl:w-1/4" style="background-image:url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/68695898ecdfe0aec572b7c008def47f/1bbd6bfe09e82b49-4b/s1280x1920/27ddc6b47bd3b099920371ea489b6328965a868d.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position:center;">
                <div class="justify-center font-black content-between w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900 h-full shadow-2xl text-white text-center font-medium"  style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
                    <div class="invisible md:visible font-logo opacity-80 justify-center font-black content-between w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900 h-24 shadow-3xl text-white text-center font-medium group-hover:hidden">
                        profiles
                    </div>
                    <div class="font-logo hidden group-hover:flex justify-center content-between w-full h-full items-center text-white text-center font-medium p-2" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
                        Bicycle rights salvia jean shorts glossier portland subway tile copper mug everyday carry photo booth hashtag kale chips taxidermy street art lo-fi church-key.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group hidden md:block justify-center flex items-center hover:grayscale min-h-full transition-width transform duration-500 bg-black xl:hover:w-3/4 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 xl:w-1/4" style="background-image:url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/41d23310270e1250b764a69ca12333ac/43a07141e3d1c30f-3b/s1280x1920/e3205b18e17a1f2cab149ec457f27213b12a7438.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position:center;">
                <div class="justify-center font-black content-between w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900  h-full text-white text-center font-medium" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
                    <div class="font-logo opacity-80 justify-center font-black content-between w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900 h-24 shadow-3xl text-white text-center font-medium group-hover:hidden">
                        videochat
                    </div>
                    <div class="font-logo hidden group-hover:flex justify-center content-between w-full h-full items-center text-white text-center font-extralight p-2" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
                        Bicycle rights salvia jean shorts glossier portland subway tile copper mug everyday carry photo booth hashtag kale chips taxidermy street art lo-fi church-key.
                        <br><br>
                        Bicycle rights salvia jean shorts glossier portland subway tile copper mug everyday carry photo booth hashtag kale chips taxidermy street art lo-fi church-key.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group hidden lg:block justify-center flex items-center hover:grayscale min-h-full transition-width transform delay-200 duration-500 bg-black xl:hover:w-3/4 w-1/4 lg:w-1/3 xl:w-1/4" style="background-image:url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/72b18c4efab196ca542512ca0bb38d06/ebad1b1c28cb53c1-2a/s1280x1920/4fb2d2ea23b1d49bc248d236ef9d408f657dfe36.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position:center;">
                <div class="justify-center font-black content-between w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900 h-full text-white text-center font-medium" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
                    <div class="font-logo opacity-80 justify-center font-black content-between w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900 h-24 shadow-3xl text-white text-center font-medium group-hover:hidden">
                        photos & videos
                    </div>
                    <div class="font-logo hidden group-hover:flex justify-center content-between w-full h-full items-center text-white text-center font-medium p-2" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
                        Bicycle rights salvia jean shorts glossier portland subway tile copper mug everyday carry photo booth hashtag kale chips taxidermy street art lo-fi church-key.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group hidden xl:block justify-center flex items-center hover:grayscale min-h-full transition-width transform delay-200 duration-500 bg-black xl:hover:w-3/4 w-1/4" style="background-image:url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/cb7c1c5c426ced74a2788bf33500b43a/f3c47dd9b7cd259b-60/s1280x1920/2590659bf867eedb7e4e2d2b8a33d3d9c3f77060.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position:center;">
                <div class="justify-center font-black content-between w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900 h-full text-white text-center font-medium" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
                    <div class="font-logo opacity-80 justify-center font-black content-between w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900 h-24 shadow-3xl text-white text-center font-medium group-hover:hidden">
                        and more...
                    </div>
                    <div class="font-logo hidden group-hover:flex justify-center content-between w-full h-full items-center text-white text-center font-medium p-2" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
                        Bicycle rights salvia jean shorts glossier portland subway tile copper mug everyday carry photo booth hashtag kale chips taxidermy street art lo-fi church-key.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/TyYSmyFtXm?layout=horizontal It's only applied to the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `div` and set class: `opacity-0 group-hover:hover:opacity-100 min-h-full transition duration-300 delay-500 flex items-center`

like this:

```
   <div class="justify-center content-between min-h-full w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900 h-full text-white text-center font-medium" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">
                    <div class="font-logo opacity-80 justify-center content-between w-full flex items-center text-3xl uppercase bg-gray-900 h-24 shadow-3xl text-white text-center font-medium group-hover:hidden">
                        photos & videos
                    </div>
                    <div class="font-logo hidden group-hover:flex justify-center content-between w-full h-full items-center text-white text-center font-medium p-2" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
                      <div class="opacity-0 group-hover:hover:opacity-100 min-h-full transition duration-300 delay-500 flex items-center">Bicycle rights salvia jean shorts glossier portland subway tile copper mug everyday carry photo booth hashtag kale chips taxidermy street art lo-fi church-key.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I came up with this solution as well but the text only shows up when you hover over the physical text. I need it to show regardless of where the cursor is on the parent div

Comment: i fixed this problem

Comment: I have accepted your answer but can you tell people what you did to fix it as this is your solution.

Comment: I built a div and set its opacity to 0 and set the height of all its parents to full so that it can be applied to it when the user hovers. When the user hovers, the opacity of the text becomes 100 and is shown with a short delay so that no clutter is detected.

Comment: If it solves your problem, please enable the green tick for people to use. tnx